# Convert VB vbCrLf to PHP

Tags: php, vbscript

New to PHP, wondering how I would convert the code below to a PHP equivalent:

```
<%= Replace(rsMyRecordset.Fields.Item("full_desc").Value, VbCrLf, "<br>") %>
```

Many thank
Tony

Answer (score 1):

Look at the [PHP Documentation for str_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)

Specifically for cr and lf, the characters are \r and \n

I would be wary of using \r\n as a line ending though. If you are sure that your text will use \r\n as line endings then you will be fine. However, it may be a good idea to look into a more thorough method of detecting line endings to replace them. PHP contains the function [nl2br](http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php) which should do this for you.

Answer (score 0):

"\r\n" is the escape code for a crlf. You might use `str_replace` combined with a foreach loop to do this in PHP.

Example:

```
foreach ($rsMyRecordset as &$value) {
    echo str_replace("\r\n", "<br>", $value);
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand, at the moment I have this line:
    <?php echo $row_rsMyRecordset['full_desc']; ?>

Whats $value

Comment: $value is a variable representing the current array index in the foreach loop. Have a look at the PHP manual for the foreach control structure for some good examples about how it works http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php